# Loop to modify a variable each iteration, and append each new "modification" to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to generate a card deck for the game SET, or, for those who don't know what that is, I'm trying to fill an array with unique elements of the form `[a, b, c, d]`, where `0 <= a, b, c, d <= 2` (81 elements). So, I want `[[0, 0, 0, 0,], [0, 0, 0, 1], ... , [2, 2, 2, 2]]` (the order doesn't matter). This is the code I have so far:

```
var deck = [],
    count = [0, 0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 0; i < 81; i++) { // go through all combos
    deck.push(count); // append the current modification of count to deck
    // increment count by 1, carrying "tens" if necessary
    for (var j = 3; count[j] === 2; j--) {
        // if the "digit" is 2, make it 0 since it overflows
        count[j] = 0;
    }
    // j is the first "digit" of count that isn't already 2, so we add 1 to it
    count[j]++;
}
```

Instead, what this seems to do is fill the `deck` array with the last modification of `count`; if the upper bound on `i` is 81, this is `[0, 0, 0, 0]` since it rolls over all the way around, and if you change the bound to anything lower it will respond accordingly. Why does this happen? What mistake have I made?

Comment: Because you push the same array to deck 81 times, so alter any of them's value will reflect to all in that array, try use `count = count.slice()` to create a new one from previous each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember that you're pushing the same `count` into `deck` each iteration, which means any alternation to count will reflect to all other `count`s in `deck`, as they're all reference to same `array`

You can use `.slice` to clone a new array with same value from previous `count`.

```js
var deck = [],
    count = [0, 0, 0, 0];
for (var i = 0; i < 81; i++) { // go through all combos

    // Clone a new array from previous one.
    count = count.slice();


    deck.push(count); // append the current modification of count to deck
    // increment count by 1, carrying "tens" if necessary
    for (var j = 3; count[j] === 2; j--) {
        // if the "digit" is 2, make it 0 since it overflows
        count[j] = 0;
    }
    // j is the first "digit" of count that isn't already 2, so we add 1 to it
    count[j]++;
}
console.log(deck);
```

Comment: How come it's the same count though? I modify it every time. I thought JS didn't reference objects like that (like Java etc)?

Comment: In your post, the item you pushed into the `deck` and the `count` are reference to same `array`, so when you modify either of them, another will reflect the change. So you need to make the count reference to a different array each iteration, then it's modification will not reflected by items in `deck`, as they're now reference to different array now.

Comment: You can find more from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: Or simply use `count=[]` to reinitiate an empty array.